# C++ and Win32 WC_DIALOG close event problem

Tags: c++, winapi

my English is bad. sorry

```
HWND DIALOG_0 = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_DIALOG, "Security Alert", DS_SETFONT | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 600,300,300,200,Win.hwnd_0,NULL,NULL,NULL);
(WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(DIALOG_0 , GWLP_WNDPROC, (INT_PTR)dede);
ShowWindow (DIALOG_0, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(DIALOG_0);
```

How do I do the shut down event.
How do I make HWND click events

I use it, but it gets locked up.

```
(WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(DIALOG_0 , GWLP_WNDPROC, (INT_PTR)dede);
```

WC_DIALOG create dede function

```
LONG_PTR __stdcall Win32::dede(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {

        case WM_CTLCOLORDLG:
            return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
        break;

        default:
            DefWindowProc(hDlg, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Show code for `dede`.

Comment: okey, source code append finish.

Comment: That is not how you subclass a window. You need to forward unhandled messages to `CallWindowProc` of the original window. Also, the way to create dialogs is `CreateDialog`, not `CreateWindowEx`. Also, that's not how you use `DS_SETFONT`. Start over: Create a dialog template, use `CreateDialog`, and specify a `DlgProc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually create dialogs with `DialogBox` or [`CreateDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialoga), not with `CreateWindow`. If you use `CreateWindow` then you cannot use the DS_ styles.

GWLP_WNDPROC replaces the original window procedure and you normally should call `CallWindowProc`, not `DefWindowProc`. If you don't do this then you don't get the default IDCANCEL handling and all the other things a dialog usually provides.

Catch `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_COMMAND` to handle close and click events.

MSDN has a dialog guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-modeless-dialog-box).

Comment: Can you offer sample that works? source code share pls?

Comment: Sample of what? You usually design a template dialog in Visual Studio and include it as a resource in your .exe/.dll.

Comment: @RamazanŞAHİN this took about 10 sec to google https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/example--the-open-dialog-box

Comment: @Anders How confusing is it with the same names because that last comment is not me.